# Limit underscorejs group by length

Tags: underscore.js

I have a long list of articles which I grouped by category, how can I limit it so each category will have only 4 (or any other number) items?

My input is:
[image]

and I want only 4 articles on each section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the object values to sliced versions of themselves:

```
_.mapObject(groupedArticles, function(group) { return group.slice(0, 4); })
```

Comment: How can I keep the structure that was before? a dictionary with an array?

Comment: This will keep the structure that was before. That's what `_.mapObject` does. It keeps the structure of the object (what you call a "dictionary"), and modifies its property values, which in this case are the arrays.